# Olives in French Beef Stew

Tags: beef, wine, stews, french-cuisine, olive

What is the use of the olives in this recipe: https://www.diningandcooking.com/38945/french-beef-stew-with-red-wine-garlic-mashed-potatoes/

In the stew, the meat gets marinated in wine and herbs, then simmered for two to three hours. Fifteen minutes before serving, pitted olives get added.

I cannot stand olives on their own so I wonder if there's a chance I will like them in here or whether I should simply leave them out.

Answer (score 5):

If the recipe said to simmer them slowly with the meat, you *might* be pleasantly surprised as they could blend in with the other flavors. (Or not, but it might be worth a try with a smaller amount.)

But in the given recipe, a not-so-small amount gets added shortly before the end of the cooking time, which seems intended to keep the original olive flavor (a bit like adding fresh herbs at the end). The flavor of the stew has developed without the olives, a few minutes won’t make a real difference. If you dislike olives on pizza, salad or as appetizer - leave them out.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the expression, "can't stand", rather than "don't care for much", I recommend leaving them out.